# Three.js draw 3D rectangle using mouse

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rectangles

So, I'm trying to draw a 3D rectangle using my mouse. After hours of trying, I kind of posted this question.

I managed to draw a resizable rectangle. I do this by editing and updating the vertices.

I've made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bgzrcx46/7/

I'm having a few problems here:

- the rectangle doesn't position it self where my mouse is when I start dragging
- the rectangle resizes in the wrong direction (if you can also make this right when rotating the camera, that'd be great)

Can anyone help me with this?

If you want the plain HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RSCEDIT - Test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #main {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="main"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/threejs/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/threejs/Detector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/threejs/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/threejs/Projector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rscedit.io/assets/client/js/threejs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var canvas = document.getElementById('main');

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: canvas
        });

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 1, 100000);

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        var controls;

        var dragging = false;

        var startPosition = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };

        var vertexSize = 2;

        onLoad();

        function onLoad() {

            canvas.onmousedown = onMouseDown;
            canvas.onmousemove = onDrag;
            canvas.onmouseup = onMouseUp;

            renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

            camera.position.set(0, 0, 25.0);
            scene.add(camera);

            /*
             * Create a Rectangle
             */
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-vertexSize, vertexSize, 0.0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertexSize, vertexSize, 0.0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertexSize, -vertexSize, 0.0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-vertexSize, -vertexSize, 0.0));
            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0xDB1E1E,
                wireframe: true
            });

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
            scene.add(mesh);

            var gridSize = 20;
            var divisions = 20;
            var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(gridSize, divisions);
            scene.add(gridHelper);

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            render();
        }

        function update(index, x, y) {
            geometry.vertices[index].set(x, y, 0);
            geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        }

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function onMouseDown(e) {
            var relative = get3DPosition(e);
            if (!relative) {
                return;
            }
            dragging = true;
            startPosition.x = e.pageX;
            startPosition.y = e.pageY;
            scene.children[1].position.set(relative.x + vertexSize, relative.y, relative.z);
            controls.enabled = false;
        }

        function onDrag(e) {
            if (dragging) {
                var clientX = (e.pageX - startPosition.x) / 50;
                var clientY = (e.pageY - startPosition.y) / 50;
                var vertices = geometry.vertices;
                vertices[1].x = clientX;
                vertices[2].x = clientX;
                vertices[2].y = -clientY;
                vertices[3].y = -clientY;
                geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            }
        }

        function onMouseUp(e) {
            dragging = false;
            controls.enabled = true;
        }

        function get3DPosition(event) {
            var offset = $(canvas).offset();
            var position = {
                x: ((event.clientX - offset.left) / canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
                y: -((event.clientY - offset.top) / canvas.clientHeight) * 2 + 1
            };
            rayCaster.setFromCamera(position, camera);
            var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                return intersects[0].point;
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your JFiddle! It will be a totally great help to something I'm working on at the moment!!

Still quite new to at all this coding at the moment but I messed around with your JFiddle and found that:

- the accuracy of the mouse to box drag was affected by the position of the camera from the grid so I locked that off and set it to orthographic as well as..
- added '* -1' to each of your vertice 'onDrag' commands (because the
  box was sizing itself in the opposite direction.
- set the initial box size to 0 to drag out from the mouse position

Here's the JFiddle to check, hope it helps! You can always change the camera back and set the `controls.enabled = false` to true again.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshyB/o2ze8qer/

Comment: That looks pretty nice. I'm quite surprised that some one solved this question. Although I don't need it anymore.

I'm creating my own rectangles (tiles) and dynamically change the materials of the vertices to mark it as selected. This is much easier.

Example: https://i.imgur.com/cFx82uR.gifv

The gif is very slow because of the PC I'm currently on. I can post a faster one when I'm home if you want.